# Piping output to executable invokes the executable multiple times

Tags: bash

I'm piping a command's output to be used as arguments for an executable:

```
command |  xargs -d '\n' "executable"
```

When the command yields sufficiently many lines of output I can see that the executable is run multiple times with sub-pages of the data each run. This is problematic because the state in the executable assumes that each invocation is independent from the next.
Is it possible to force the "command" to feed the entire output in a single go to the executable?

Comment: There's a limit on the size of the argument list. `xargs` ensures that it doesn't exceed the limit.

Comment: @gwow12345: Your requirement implies that you have so much output to process that it exceeds the size of a command line (because otherwise, `xargs`  would handle it). In this case, I suggest that you rewrite your _executable_ to read its input from stdin instead of the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `xargs`, use `$(...)` to substitute the output into the command line.

```
IFS=$'\n' # this is analogous to -d '\n' in xargs
set -o noglob # prevent wildcard expansion when substituting command output
executable $(command)
```

However, this could get an error if the output of `command` is too long. `xargs` splits it up into multiple invocations to prevent this. But if you really require everything to be in one invocation, the error is the way to tell that this isn't possible, and prevents the incorrect results due to multiple invocations.

Comment: I see.
I do get the error.
I'll handle it by redirect the output to a file and have the program read from the file. Is there any best practices otherwise, or will this be accepted by the next maintainer?

Comment: @gwow12345 Why use a file? You can read directly from stdin so that you can write `command | executable`.

Comment: @Barmar : I don't think that `$(...)` is a good idea here. The `-d '\n'` suggests that the OP wants that each line is presentet to  the executable as one argument. If you do command replacement, each word would become a separate argument.

Comment: @user1934428 That's the reason for setting `IFS`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to force the "command" to feed the entire output in a single go to the executable?

Yes and no.

To run the executable only once, you can use

```
command | bash -c 'mapfile -t a; executable "${a[@]}"'
```

However, this might fail if you exceed `ARG_MAX` of your system. A program invocation together with its arguments and environment variables must be smaller than `ARG_MAX` bytes. (On Linux there is even an additional restriction limiting the [size of each single argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/187122)). There is no way around this.

You can check your `ARG_MAX` using `getconf ARG_MAX` or `xargs --show-limits < /dev/null`. [This website](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/) compiled a nice list of the values on various systems.

If you are barely over the maximum and don't need environment variables, you can clear the environment to make some space.

```
command | env -i bash -c 'mapfile -t a; executable "${a[@]}"'
```

Other than that there is no way but to run `executable` multiple times or modify it, preferably so that it read lines from stdin instead of arguments. That way you can write

```
command | executable
```